# Convert a number into the hex value in .NET

Tags: c#, string, hex

I need to convert an integer number to the hex value. It will look like this:

**0x0201cb77192c851c**

When I do

```
string hex = int.ToString("x")
```

in C#, it returns

```
201cb77192c851c
```

How can I get the required result?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One way would be to append the number of digits you need, after "x". This will pad the output with leading zeros as necessary.

```
"0x" + myLong.ToString("x16");
```

or

```
string.Format("0x{0:x16}", myLong);
```

From [The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString)
:

> The precision specifier indicates the
>   minimum number of digits desired in
>   the resulting string. If required, the
>   number is padded with zeros to its
>   left to produce the number of digits
>   given by the precision specifier.

Answer (score 8):

```
string hex = "0x" + int.ToString("x16")
```

Comment: should be 'int.ToString("x8")', or? 4 bytes, two places = 8